# Why the tensorflow script doesn't work?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm learning tensorflow and got a strange error. When I type the code in a text editor and run it as a .py file, it doesn't work, but if I type it line by line in python interactive command line, it works well and gives expected result. This code is from official tutorial:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
features = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("x", dimension=1)]
estimator = tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=features)
x = np.array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
y = np.array([0., -1., -2., -3.])
input_fn = tf.contrib.learn.io.numpy_input_fn({"x":x}, y, batch_size=4,num_epochs=1000)

estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn, steps=1000)

estimator.evaluate(input_fn=input_fn)
```

using `python tf_contrib_learn_basic_usage.py`, it results:

```
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:135] successfu
lly opened CUDA library cublas64_80.dll locally
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:135] successfu
lly opened CUDA library cudnn64_5.dll locally
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:135] successfu
lly opened CUDA library cufft64_80.dll locally
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:135] successfu
lly opened CUDA library nvcuda.dll locally
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:135] successfu
lly opened CUDA library curand64_80.dll locally
WARNING:tensorflow:Using temporary folder as model directory: C:\Users\ljxfo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpvx8ucski
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('
op: "BestSplits" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: BestSplits
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('
op: "CountExtremelyRandomStats" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: CountExtremelyRandomStats
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('
op: "FinishedNodes" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: FinishedNodes
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('
op: "GrowTree" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: GrowTree
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('
op: "ReinterpretStringToFloat" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: ReinterpretStringToFloat
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('
op: "SampleInputs" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: SampleInputs
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('
op: "ScatterAddNdim" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: ScatterAddNdim
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('
op: "TopNInsert" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TopNInsert
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('
op: "TopNRemove" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TopNRemove
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('
op: "TreePredictions" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TreePredictions
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('
op: "UpdateFertileSlots" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: UpdateFertileSlots
WARNING:tensorflow:Rank of input Tensor (1) should be the same as output_rank (2) for column. Will attempt to expand dim
s. It is highly recommended that you resize your input, as this behavior may change.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\ljxfo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\le
arn\python\learn\estimators\head.py:1362: scalar_summary (from tensorflow.python.ops.logging_ops) is deprecated and will
 be removed after 2016-11-30.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.summary.scalar. Note that tf.summary.scalar uses the node name instead of the tag. This means that T
ensorFlow will automatically de-duplicate summary names based on the scope they are created in. Also, passing a tensor o
r list of tags to a scalar summary op is no longer supported.
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:885] F
ound device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GT 635M
major: 2 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 0.95
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 2.00GiB
Free memory: 1.65GiB
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:906] D
MA: 0
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:916] 0
:   Y
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:948] I
gnoring visible gpu device (device: 0, name: GeForce GT 635M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0) with Cuda compute capability 2.1
. The minimum required Cuda capability is 3.0.
WARNING:tensorflow:Rank of input Tensor (1) should be the same as output_rank (2) for column. Will attempt to expand dim
s. It is highly recommended that you resize your input, as this behavior may change.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\ljxfo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\le
arn\python\learn\estimators\head.py:1362: scalar_summary (from tensorflow.python.ops.logging_ops) is deprecated and will
 be removed after 2016-11-30.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.summary.scalar. Note that tf.summary.scalar uses the node name instead of the tag. This means that T
ensorFlow will automatically de-duplicate summary names based on the scope they are created in. Also, passing a tensor o
r list of tags to a scalar summary op is no longer supported.
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:948] I
gnoring visible gpu device (device: 0, name: GeForce GT 635M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0) with Cuda compute capability 2.1
. The minimum required Cuda capability is 3.0.
WARNING:tensorflow:Skipping summary for global_step, must be a float or np.float32.
```

I understand that my laptop with gtx635m is not perfectly supported with cuda, but the code works well when typed line by line. So what's wrong with this?

Comment: Those look like warnings to me. Are you using tensorflow 1.0.0?

Comment: But there are things like `unknown op`, and no results. Yes, I'm using 1.0.0

Comment: They have addressed that on [tensorflow github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7500), tensorflow 1.0.0 on windows causes those warnings. You can try a nightly build. But it should work either way, have you tried printing something after your calculations, so you can see whether it works or not?

Comment: Thanks for that, I add a print after each line and it seems that `estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn, steps=1000)` is not working. I got warnings in interactive environment, but I can still get the result. It's really wired.

Comment: What happens after you call `estimator.fit(...)` to make you think it's not working? (@umutto is correct about the warnings, and upgrading to TensorFlow 1.1 should get rid of them.)

Comment: An hour ago I tried to install the nightly build and it seems work now, but some other warnings like the github issue umutto has given. It seems that there's still no perfect solution now for windows.